# iPhone Safari: Scroll a list inside a html container

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari

I did a lot of research about this topic and didn't yet find a satisfying answer:

How can I make a scrollable list (iPhone SDK Dashboard List) inside some other html content? If I create a list inside a html body and I try to scroll the whole page is scrolled. I know there is this "double finger" scrolling, but that's not what i want.

Is there some way to prevent the whole iPhone Safari Webpage from scrolling and instead letting other lists inside scroll? Like redirecting java script events?

Background: the idea is to mimic a real native application behavior with tabs at the bottom and a selection list in the body.

Appreciate any hints!
Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is yet another possibility, with slightly nicer scrolling simulation:
http://cubiq.org/scrolling-div-on-iphone-ipod-touch/5

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after consulting some friends, I found the answer to this question:

http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/

have fun.

Answer (score 0):

http://cubiq.org/scrolling-div-on-iphone-ipod-touch/5
this is a really great script!! It's smaller than the doctyper version and easier to work with since it doesn't have so many elements being repositioned.  It also allows contained elements to be touched easier by the user.  and even cooler, when you touch into a text field and the close the type panel the divs being positioned by this script snap right back into place (where as the doctyper version just has them floating out of place after the type screen retracts).

A very nice script.

Answer (score 0):

A new scrolling library to keep an eye on: [Scrollability](http://joehewitt.github.com/scrollability/).