# get viewport position in javascript in iphone safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, safari, webkit

I'm trying to prevent element from scrolling in safari on iphone. I've tried solutions mentioned here:
[iPhone Safari: Scroll a list inside a html container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777621/iphone-safari-scroll-a-list-inside-a-html-container)
But my list is large and it doesn't work so smoothly.

What I have in mind is to detect onscroll event and reposition the element, so it's in the boundaries of viewport.

But I can't find way to detect coordinates of the viewport. Can anybody help with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener(
    'touchmove',
    function touchMove(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
    },
    false
);
```

Comment: I think you may also need  event.stopPropagation()

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll).  If is doesn't do what you want, you can use the implementation for reference.  I think the trick so to do both `event.preventDefault()` and  `event.stopPropagation()` to keep mobile safari from responding to the touch events.

> iScroll was born because
>   mobile webkit (on iPhone, iPod,
>   Android and Pre) does not provide a
>   native way to scroll content inside a
>   fixed width/height element. This
>   unfortunate situation prevents any
>   web-app to have a position:absolute
>   header and/or footer and a scrolling
>   central area for contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
var viewport_x = window.pageXOffset;
var viewport_y = window.pageYOffset;
```

Comment: This should be `window.pageXOffset` and `window.pageYOffset`